# Unrecognized expression '$push' in MONGODB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This is how my sample QUESTION array is:

```
[
        {
            "subject": "app development",
            "topic": "dart",
            "subtopic": "flutter2",
            "questionType": "EASY",
            "questionTitle": "how angular works",
        },
        {
            "subject": "app development",
            "topic": "dart",
            "subtopic": "flutter",
            "questionType": "EASY",
            "questionTitle": "how angular works",
            
        },
        {
            "subject": "app development",
            "topic": "javascript",
            "subtopic": "react native",
            "questionType": "EASY",
            "questionTitle": "how angular works",
      
        },
    ]
```

I need to group the `subject` field into, and `topic` into an array.

This is how I want:

```
{
            "subject": "web development",
            "topics":[{ 
                topicName:"javascript", 
                subtopics:[
                        "react native,
                        "flutter"
                ]
               }]
}
```

I'm trying to do it this way but this error:

> "Unrecognized expression '$push'" shows

```
{
          $group: {
            _id: "$subject",
            topics: {
              $addToSet: {
                title: "$topic",
                sub: {$push:"$subtopic"},
              },
            },
          },
        },
```

I need to get an array of grouped `subjects` and `topics` and `subtopics`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$group` can not support nested operations `$addToSet` and `$push` at the same time, you need to divide both the operations into different `$group` stages,

- `$group` by `subject` and `topic` and construct the unique array of `subtopic` using `$addToSet`
- `$group` by only `subject` and construct the array of `topics`
- `$project` to format and show required fields

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        subject: "$subject",
        topic: "$topic"
      },
      subtopic: { $addToSet: "$subtopic" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.subject",
      topics: {
        $push: {
          topic: "$_id.topic",
          sub: "$subtopic"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      subject: "$_id",
      topics: 1
    }
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uo8cMK-9N0t)